# angular material table - how to fit rows vertically to outer container

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material table usually has fixed number of rows. But I want to pre-calculate that number somehow first, so the table fits into the outer container. I'm thinking just making a simple math here - take the ((container height - header_height) / one_row_height).

Is there any other way I wonder?

(Angular v.10)

Comment: Maybe just add css rule `overflow: hidden` to the container?

Comment: and that will hide the rows that are below the container... interesting solution :)